# First customized problem - struggling to find constraints

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am new to OptaPlanner (and Constraint Satisfaction Programming) and after following the cloud balancing tutorial i wanted to model my first customized problem, but i struggle to find the correct constraints for the solver.

The problem:
I have a group of people which i want to seperate into two different groups based on their semester and faculty.
In this specific case every person in group one should have the same semester(and faculty) as the semester and faculty the group has and everyone else should be in group two.

My specific data:
Group_1 : reqSemester : 7 , reqFaculty : 2
Group_2 : reqSemester : 0 , reqFaculty : 0

Person_1: semester : 7 , faculty : 2
Person_2: semester : 6 , faculty : 1
Person_3: semester : 8 , faculty : 3

My constraints:

```
 int semesterDiff = group.getSemester() - semester;
 if (semesterDiff == 0){
      hardScore += semester;
 }
 int facultyDiff = group.getFaculty() - faculty;
 if (facultyDiff == 0){
      hardScore += faculty;
 }
```

The result i expected:
Group_1 : Person_1
Group_2 : Person_2, Person_3

The result i got:
Group_1 : Person_2, Person_1
Group_2 : Person_3

**Note:** switching the constraints from == to != will fix my problem, but when i add more people it will "fail" again.

**Edit:** added the complete (and extended) code of the score rules.

```
public class LoudBalancingScoreRules implements EasyScoreCalculator<Problem> {

public HardSoftScore calculateScore(Problem problem) {

    int softScore = 0;
    int hardScore = 0;

    for (Group group : problem.getListGroup()) {
        int semester = 0;
        int faculty = 0;

        for (Person person : problem.getPersonList()) {
            if (group.equals(person.getGroup())) {
                semester = person.getSemester();
                faculty = person.getFb();
            }
        }
        int semesterDiff = group.getSemester() - semester;
        if (semesterDiff == 0){
            hardScore += semester;

        }
        int facultyDiff = group.getFb() - faculty;
        if (facultyDiff == 0){
            hardScore += faculty;
        }

        if (semesterDiff != 0){
            hardScore += -Math.abs(semesterDiff);
        }

        if (facultyDiff != 0){
            hardScore += -Math.abs(facultyDiff);
        }
    }
    return HardSoftScore.of(hardScore, softScore);
}
```

As I've shown, it doesn't quite work as I expected and im not able to find my mistake. If anyone can figure out where im going wrong it would be a great help.

Comment: Do you have a negative score? You should, because it's a negative hard constraint.

Comment: Also read the docs section "Score Trap", for once it might actually apply here. Personally, I 'd just penalize every pair of assignments that shouldn't be in the same group together.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet The score i get is 9. I've added the code to penalize the pair as you said (if I understood correctly) which resulted in a score of -2 and every person being assigned to group_1.

Comment: Penalize only the pairs that should be in different groups.